# Do different things on each iteration of a loop c#

Tags: c#, sifteo

I am making a game for children on the Sifteo Cubes. I am trying to load a sentence on the cubes, word by word. I have some experience with the Sifteo Cubes but how can I solve this in a more beautiful way? More generic if that's possible.

```
foreach (CubeWrapper wrapper in mWrappers) {
            if (i == 0) { 
                wrapper.setWord (w1);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                wrapper.setWord (w2);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                wrapper.setWord (w3);
            } else if (i == 3) {
                wrapper.setWord (w4);
            } else if (i == 4) {
                wrapper.setWord (w5);
            }
            i++;
        }
```

I will always add w1 to the first wrapper and so on.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
String[] words = new String[] {w1,w2,w3,w4,w5};

foreach (CubeWrapper wrapper in mWrappers) 
{
   wrapper.setWord(words[i++]);
}
```

This solution is working, but keep in mind, if the `words` array is smaller than the `mWrappers` collection you will receive a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. So syncing the access to the array is now your work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't\don't want to change your class then you could use reflection to do something like this (**Even though it's probably not the right thing to do here**):

```
foreach (CubeWrapper wrapper in mWrappers) {   
    var name = "w" + (i+1).ToString();
    var value = this.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(this);
    wrapper.setWord(value);
}
```

Example:

```
public class ABC
{
    public int w1 { get; set; }
    public int w2 { get; set; }
    public int w3 { get; set; }

    public ABC()
    {
        w1 = 7;
        w2 = 8;
        w3 = 9;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var i = 1;
        var name = "w" + (i + 1).ToString(); // w2
        var value = (int)this.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(this);
        DoSomething(value);
    }

    public void DoSomething(int curr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(curr); // 8
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
abc.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Wow, are you sure reflection is a practical and applicable solution here? I think this is like shooting with canons on flies.

Comment: @ckruczek - 1. It solves the problem without code refactoring(which you can't always do). 2. You're solution isn't the best solution as well. Since if one of the w var's value changes then your array will have the previous value.

Comment: Of course I am not saying my solution is the best one. But your isn't neither. If the name of the variable names changes from 'w' to something different you have to do a code refactoring. Despite this fact, your variable naming will always result in `w2`. Reflection is definitly not a applicable solution here. BUT having this said, we both can be wrong because the OP didn't specified his domain very well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random word from the array, using Random class like this...

```
        String[] words = new String[] { "w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5" };
        Random r = new Random(0);
        int randomNumber = r.Next(0, words.Length);

        foreach (CubeWrapper wrapper in mWrappers)
        {
            wrapper.setWord(words[randomNumber]);
        }
```